# Find ProcessorId and Cpu Usage of all running processes

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cpu-usage, ps

**Background**

I want to find the cpu core id and utilization of each and every process running in my system.

I have used `ps -eF` to get cpu core id and `ps -aux` to get cpu utilization.

**Query**

I want to know, is there any way to get both the things using a single command or any specific options that is available in `ps` command to retrieve both the things?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: are you aware of the `top` command? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `-o` option to your `ps -ef` to add additional columns to the output.  The format specifiers are documented in the [ps man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) in the Standard Format Specifiers section.
For example:

`ps -efo %cpu` or `ps -efo pcpu`

Additionally, you can run this command to list all valid format specifiers:

`ps L`

Comment: ps -eo psr,%cpu,pid | grep "^  1" | head